# Can i use 4 Action button in Notification manager ? like B1, B2, B3, B4

Tags: android

I am using Notification Manager and have added 4 action button like YES, NO, MAYBE, LATER. But, 4th button is not showing.

What could be the possible reason...? 
Kindly guide.

Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

### With respect to NotificationCompat.Builder

Not exactly a simple answer, you need to read the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action)

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Style.html

### Simple answer (With respect to NotifcationBuilder)

No this is not possible with NotificationBuilder, but you can create your own custom remote view to achieve this, but you'll want to think about this option carefully, as it will require extra maintenance.

### Reason why NotificationBuilder.addAction(...) can't take > 3 buttons

Try reading the APIs you are using:

```
<Notification.Builder>.addAction(...)
```

It has a limitation:

> **A notification in its expanded form can display up to 3 actions**, from left to right in the order they were added. Actions will not be displayed when the notification is collapsed, however, so be sure that any essential functions may be accessed by the user in some other way (for example, in the Activity pointed to by contentIntent).

### Ref

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(int, java.lang.CharSequence, android.app.PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent))